# Test that confirms that the method signature has not been changed?

Tags: java, junit, types, casting, type-conversion

**This is a hypothetical situation. I'm using int as the type, but you may freely replace it with any type of your choosing, this is a question about how to write a test that confirms that no one has changed the method signature.**

I've written an method that works very well with integers, but will produce very difficult to track down bugs if it ever receives certain non-integers. I want to avoid bugs, so I've written some tests to confirm that the method works correctly. I'm writing in Java, so I can happily rely upon Java's strong typing. However, someday, someone is going to want to change this method to accept some non-integers (probably me), and it will work, sometimes (I'll be very proud of myself). They (I) might even write some tests to add to their improved version of the method and those tests will pass, unless they pass certain non-integers.

**Is it possible to write a test that confirms that the method signature has not changed?**

I've tried this, but `myClass.multiply(2.0, 2);` does not compile so I can't run the test.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class TestingCoercion {

    @Test
    public void multiply2x2() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        Assert.assertEquals(myClass.multiply(2, 2), 4);
    }

    @Test
    public void multiplyDoesNotWorkWithFloat() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        try {
            myClass.multiply(2.0, 2); //this line does not compile
            fail("MyClass.multiply is only for integers");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Assert.assertTrue("MyClass.multiply correctly rejected a double", true);
        }
    }


    class MyClass {
        public int multiply(int i, int j) {
            return i * j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"but myClass.multiply(2.0, 2); does not compile so I can't run the test."`: isn't that reliable enough? If another developer can change the method signature, they can also change the unit tests, or the method implementation itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use reflection to find a specific method with a specific parameter list.

You could do something like this:

```
try {
    MyClass.class.getMethod("multiply", int.class, int.class);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException) {
    // test has failed.
    fail(); //do not swallow this exception, fail the test
}
```

`getMethod` will throw a `NoSuchMethodException` if there is no method with that exact parameter list.

If you want to also check that no one has added another overload that you may accidentally call in the future, you can as well:

```
assertEquals(1, Arrays.stream(MyClass.class.getMethods()).filter(x -> x.getName().equals("multiply")).count());
```